# jQuery default Selected year and month on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to get auto selected current month and year on page load with current validation i.e. current selected year will only show current month and past month in month selection field.

i tried .load() function but event listener is not working in page load.

```js
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
var cascadedDropDownMonthId = "#dropDownYearMonth";

//Adding Last 10 Years to Year Drop Down
for (var i = currentYear;i > currentYear - 10 ; i--)
{
$("#dropDownYear1").append('<option value="'+ i.toString() +'">' +i.toString() +'</option>');
}
 
//Disabling Month Dropdown in case of invalid Selections.
//$(cascadedDropDownMonthId).prop("disabled", true);

$("#dropDownYear1").change(function () {

            var currentSelectedValue = $(this).val();
            
            if (currentSelectedValue == "-1")
            {
                $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).prop("disabled", true);
            }
            else
            {
                $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).prop("disabled", false);
                //Get Current Year from Dropdown and Converting to Integer for performing math operations
                var currentSelectedYear = parseInt($(this).val());
               
                //As Index of Javascript Month is from 0 to 11 therefore totalMonths are 11 NOT 12
                var totalMonths = 11;
                if (currentSelectedYear == currentYear) {
                    totalMonths = currentMonth;
                }
                var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
                //Emptying the Month Dropdown to clear our last values
               $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).empty();
                
               // $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).append('<option value="-1">-Month-</option>');                                

                //Appending Current Valid Months
                for (var month = 0; month <= totalMonths; month++) {
                    $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).append('<option value="'+ (month+1) +  '">' + monthNames[month] + '</option>');
                }
            }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    
<select id="dropDownYear1">

</select>
<select id="dropDownYearMonth">
    
</select>
```

Comment: Where is your code that uses the page load event listener?

Comment: @kmoser, i think i said i tried .load() event but this doesn't worked out.

Comment: @kmoser ```$("#dropDownYear1").load(function ()``` will doesn't show any month in month selector, but on change it shows month in month selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `document ready` function to load current `months` and `years`.

You need to wrap you `current year months` in a function and call that function on `DOM` ready.

In that function `loadMonths` we need to pass the `current month` and then check the length of month names and append only the remanning month of the `current` year.

In your `onchange` function we can simply check if the `selected` year is `current` year and on that we can call `loadMonths()` function which will show current year remaining `months` only OR else if year is not `current` then all months will be `appended` to months dropdown.

**Edit:** Current month by default will be shown on load as you wanted.

**Demo:**

```js
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
var cascadedDropDownMonthId = "#dropDownYearMonth";
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

//Adding current months on load
function loadMonths(curr) {
  //Adding Last 10 Years to Year Drop Down
  for (var i = currentYear; i > currentYear - 10; i--) {
    $("#dropDownYear1").append('<option value="' + i.toString() + '">' + i.toString() + '</option>');
  }
  //Months
  for (i = 0; i <= curr; i++) {
    $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).append('<option selected value="' + (i + 1) + '">' + monthNames[i] + '</option>');
  }
}

//on change function
$('#dropDownYear1').on('change', function() {

  var currentSelectedValue = $(this).val();

  if (currentSelectedValue == "-1") {
    $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).prop("disabled", false);
    //Get Current Year from Dropdown and Converting to Integer for performing math operations
    var currentSelectedYear = parseInt($(this).val());

    //As Index of Javascript Month is from 0 to 11 therefore totalMonths are 11 NOT 12
    var totalMonths = 11;

    //Emptying the Month Dropdown to clear our last values
    $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).empty();

    // $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).append('<option value="-1">-Month-</option>');                                
    //Appending Current Valid Months
    if (currentSelectedYear == currentYear) {
      //Calling current month if year is current
      loadMonths(currentMonth)
      //total month
      totalMonths = currentMonth;
    } else {
      //If not current year load all months
      for (var month = 0; month <= totalMonths; month++) {
        $(cascadedDropDownMonthId).append('<option value="' + (month + 1) + '">' + monthNames[month] + '</option>');
      }
    }
  }
})

// execute the function when the page loads
$(document).ready(loadMonths(currentMonth));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="dropDownYear1">

</select>
<select id="dropDownYearMonth">

</select>
```

Comment: in 2020 month should be current and past month but it shows future month

Comment: sure, but my question is instead of selecting first month can i select current_month by_default on load?

Comment: @rock Sure - Please see the updated answer. Working exactly as you wanted.